# How do I allow Visual Studio Code to process .ai (adobe illustrator) extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to create NFT's using Visual Studio Code, however, the image layers (.ai) are not recognized by VSC. What do I need to do to make this extension work with VSC? Thank you for your time.

Comment: NFT (???). Which extension do you use or write yourself?

Answer (score 0):

VSCode does not natively support anything that has to do with `.ai` files. You will need an extension ("plugin") for vscode to make it work **if it even exists**... From what I found an extension that supports image editing with layers is [Luna Paint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.luna-paint). However, it doesn't say anything about supporting `.ai` files. I hope you find a way around of what you want to accomplish!